# SSRS Report Log error

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am new to SSRS, In my application so many reports are using SSRS that too big reports.

In the report logs I am getting these errors

```
 Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: There is no data for the field at position 14.;
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: There is no data for the field at position 21.;
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: There is no data for the field at position 5.;
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: There is no data for the field at position 7.;
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: There is no data for the field at position 8.;
```

I cross checked whether dataset is returning any NULL and I had given default some values to it, but still these errors are coming.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link. It says there is a missing field in dataset: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8f4e23bb-2e04-4e07-a914-894b6a9ff5e8/microsoftreportingservicesreportprocessingreportprocessingexception-there-is-no-data-for-the?forum=sqlreportingservices